# Forecasting an ADL model

Tags: forecasting, stata, ardl

I am fairly new to Stata, currently taking an undergrad time series econometric class. The economic significance of the regression I am running and attempting to forecast is all but zero; this is simply my learning how to use Stata somewhat efficiently. I have run an Autoregressive Distributed Lag (ADL) regression of Industrial Production (`ip`) using two lags of `ip` and one lag of the Federal Funds Rate (`ffr`).

My goal: forecast this model 30 periods into the future. I was hoping I could run an AR(2) model of the `ffr` and forecast it 30 periods (this is straightforward and I have done so) and then use these values to forecast my ADL model 30 periods.

Does this make sense and could someone inform me on how I could do this or suggest another method?

Comment: Is this mainly about what makes sense statistically or do you seek Stata support? If the latter, it is arguably off-topic here (and would not be well received on SO, but you do not show a programming problem). In either case, please explain ADL and please don't assume that abbreviations used in your field make sense to all readers.

Comment: It is on the latter so I apologize for posting off-topic. By ADL I meant Autoregressive Distributed Lag.